# When there is a touch in a CGRect, do something (Cocos2d Question)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2d and I am making a game with a SneakyJoystick and a SneakyButton. The SneakyJoystick works fine, it moves the sprite character around the screen. But the SneakyButton is a problem. How do I implement shooting another sprite from the characters position when the SneakyButton is pressed? Do I modify the SneakyButton.h and SneakyButton.m? Or do I recreate the code in the HelloWorldLayer.h and HelloWorldLayer.m? This is extremely confusing and please remember that I am using a SneakyButton, not a button that I programmed myself. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you post some links to SneakyButton code or API? Can't seem to find anything other than forum questions on Google.

Comment: @lins314159 Sure. Here is the tutorial to use it: [Here](http://www.qcmat.com/sneakyinput-joystick-dpad-and-buttons-for-cocos2d/)

Comment: Can you post your current code? From what I'm reading, SneakyJoystick and SneakyButton work in similar ways, so there's probably only a minor detail preventing you from getting the latter working if you already have the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to modify the code. You just include the SneakyInput code in your project. Then import the SneakyButton headers in your class. Create the instance of SneakyButton and add it to your layer. Then you can just query the state of button if it is pressed or not.
Its very simple, just follow this tutorial from link below,

http://www.qcmat.com/sneakyinput-joystick-dpad-and-buttons-for-cocos2d/

Comment: What do you mean create the instance of SneakyButton?

Comment: SneakyButtonSkinnedBase *rightBut = [[[SneakyButtonSkinnedBase alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: Just like above statement you can create instance. Just see the sample code on above mentioned link. It explains step by step procedure to add SneekyButton and works great !!

Comment: okay, i got it to work. I had to use the BOOL isActive thing.